# Mongo index swap determination

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database-indexes, database

I have mongo server with big data. And my queries (by indexes) take a lot of time (several minutes or more). All look like there is no enough memory for indexes loading and mongo forced to swap them to hard drive. But I want to be sure this is so.

Could you tell me please how I can check this?
(I need something like swap log)

Comment: Voted to migrate this to http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, can I do it myself?

Comment: Nope. To give you a quick idea, you should use CloudManager (the cloud monitoring service at http://cloud.mongodb.com). An easy and quick way is to connect to your instance using the mongo shell, and issue `use <yourDbName>; db.stats()` which will output index sizes. As a rule of thumb: if >90% of your RAM is used, you can be sure that MongoDB needs to swap / reread indices. Combine that with spinning disks and very large datasets, the performance becomes crap.

Comment: I check index size (by db.stats()) and >90% my RAM is really used. So it  look like swapping. But I want to be sure! :)

Comment: If it smells like a dog, looks like a dog and barks like a dog it is probably a dog...